# How to run this Docker command from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my command:

`docker run -d --name di MY_DOCKER_IMAGE/cli start accept --token your_token_here`

I want to run the contaniner with my image and this parameters from Dockerfile.

Example:

```
FROM my_docker_image:latest

CMD -d --name di MY_DOCKER_IMAGE/cli start accept --token your_token_here
```

Something like this that when runs the container image runs with the specified parameters and not just pull the image.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for `docker compose` https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#compose-file-structure-and-examples

Comment: Can you write me an example code? I don't know where to put the parameters in the code in docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

With docker compose, you can run your container with those parameters by doing

```
docker compose up -d
```

Create a file called docker-compose.yml and put this inside it

```
version: '3'

services:
  di:
    image: MY_DOCKER_IMAGE/cli
    container_name: di
    command: start accept --token your_token_here
```

Then, when you do `docker compose up -d`, your container will be started with the same parameters as in your `docker run` command.

Depending on your version of docker compose, you might have to use `docker-compose up -d` (with a dash in 'docker-compose').

Comment: (You don't need the `container_name:` option for most typical uses.)

Comment: That's true, but it's needed if you want to mimic OP's `docker run` command, isn't it? Otherwise, the container will be named `<project name>_di`.

Answer (score -1):

The `CMD` command is just to run one command INSIDE the container. If you want to run something like you descripted in your post you should take a look at `docker-compose` like @Jeffrey Mixon mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).